# i want to group by using particular column but same time i need to concatenate

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

The following is an example:

```
Table A

project Name amount  detail    department    supervisor
 1234  angel  200     water      utility      you
 234     B     200     house      retail       me
 235     C     400      air      environment   where
 1234  angel  200     water     department     son
 234     B     200     house      retail       me
 235     C     400     treat      environment   where
 1234  angel  200     water      utility      you
 234     B     200     house      retail       me
 235     C     400      air      environment   where
```

output of the SQL should be -

```
project   Name   amount   detail    department     supervisor
1234     angel    200      water       utility      you,son
234        B      200       house       retail       me
235        C      400      air,treat   environment    where
```

remove duplicate type also distinct like..

well I tried using LISTAgg but the issue is I need to group it by project  and don`t want to group it my detail and detail column but i need a distinct values to be passed in detail  and supervisor column hope some one can help

Comment: i think row `1234  angel  200     water     department     son` is `1234  angel  200     water     utility     son`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may join three nested subqueries and use `distinct` or `unique` to get rid of `duplicates` :

```
select distinct * from
(
 select dt.project, dt.Name, dt.amount, details, departments, supervisors 
   from
 (select project, Name, amount, listagg(detail, ',') within group (order by detail) details
   from ( select unique project, Name, amount, detail from a )
  group by project, Name, amount) dt
inner join
 (select project, Name, amount, listagg(department, ',') within group (order by department) departments
    from ( select unique project, Name, amount, department from a )
   group by project, Name, amount) dp on (dt.project=dp.project)
inner join
  (select project, Name, amount, listagg(supervisor, ',') within group (order by supervisor desc) supervisors
     from ( select unique project, Name, amount, supervisor from a )
    group by project, Name, amount) sp on (dt.project=sp.project)
)
order by lower(name);
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0b669/6)

Comment: cant we write all the listagg in one sub query

Comment: @palkodi sorry but it was very hard to try this, accomplishing with one sub-query would be very difficult without duplicates.

Comment: is there any other method other than listagg for this which we can use distinct value while we concatenate.

Comment: @palkodi sorry, i don't know. Suppose may be done with pl/sql instead of sql with some more tries.

Answer (score 1):

This is a painful problem because you need to eliminate duplicates.  `listagg()` does not support `distinct`.

So, multiple subqueries are needed for each one:

```
select a.project, a.name, a.amount, a.department, ad.details, asu.supervisors
from a join
     (select project, listagg(detail, ',') within group (order by project) as details
      from (select distinct project, name, amount, department, detail
            from a
           ) a
      group by project
     ) ad
     on ad.project = a.project join
     (select project, listagg(supervisor, ',') within group (order by project) as supervisors
      from (select distinct project, name, amount, department, supervisor
            from a
           ) a
      group by project
     ) asu
     on asu.project = a.project   
group by project, name, amount, department;
```

Comment: excuse me but gives `ORA-00904: "AD"."PROJECT": invalid identifier` as result ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0b669/2 )

Comment: @Gordon well if u do distinct also up der when u do listagg still u get same . it didn`t worked for me in toad